# inline jquery string - add bold font to certain words

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an inline string of jquery that displays a dynamic string of text as shown below:

```
$( "#submit_buttonA" ).attr('update-confirm', '{% trans "Are you sure you want to change the language of the website from" %} ' + $('#id_language_code option[value=' + '{{ user.get_profile.language_preference }}' + ']').text() + ' {% trans "to" %} ' + $('#id_language_code option[value=' + newLanguageCode + ']').text() + '{% trans "?" %}');
```

This gives me the following:

Are you sure you want to change the language of the website from português (Brasil) to Italiano - italiano?

I am now trying to make the language names in a bold font, but each approach I take, renders the < b>< /b> characters to the screen.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

Are you sure you want to change the language of the website from **português (Brasil)** to **Italiano - italiano**?

So I tried the following:

```
$( "#submit_buttonA" ).attr('update-confirm', '{% trans "Are you sure you want to change the language of the website from" %}<b> ' + $('#id_language_code option[value=' + '{{ user.get_profile.language_preference }}' + ']').text() + '</b> {% trans "to" %}<b> ' + $('#id_language_code option[value=' + newLanguageCode + ']').text() + '</b>{% trans "?" %}');
```

This is what I get:

Are you sure you want to change the language of the website from < b>português (Brasil)< /b> to < b>Italiano - italiano< /b>?

**EDIT: added code as per request**

```
        $('a[update-confirm]').click(function(ev) {

        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        if (!$('#updateConfirmModal').length) {

            //please wait included in the line of code below.
            $('body').append('<div id="updateConfirmModal" class="modal modal-confirm-max-width" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="updateConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><icon class="icon-remove"></icon></button><h4 class="modal-title" id="updateConfirmLabel">{% trans "Confirm Language Change" %}</h4></div><div class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">{% trans "Cancel" %}</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="visible-phone"><br /></span><a class="btn-u btn-u-blue" id="updateConfirmOK" onclick="submitForm();showProgressAnimation();">{% trans "Update Language View" %} - {% trans "Language Change" %}</a></div></div>');

        }

        $('#updateConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('update-confirm'));

        $('#updateConfirmOK').attr('href', href);

        $('#updateConfirmModal').modal({show:true});

        return false;

    });
```

Comment: in your selector use html() instead of text()

Comment: Changing the .text() to .html() does not work as the text required to be bold is outside the .text/.html. Even if I encapsulate the bold text in .html, the html bold < b>< /b> is still rendered to the screen.

Comment: **html() parse only valid html tags**.. your text values will remain untouched

Comment: I cannot get this working, can you give me an example?

Comment: you are placing the ENTIRE string inside an attribute 'update-confirm'.. please send over the code that **prints** it to the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line:

```
$('#updateConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('update-confirm'));
```

to this line:

```
 $('#updateConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').html($(this).attr('update-confirm'));
```

**please reffer to the comment in the original post to follow the entire process**

Comment: Ahhhhh! I get it now. I was changing the .html() in the wrong place. Face Palm.

Comment: it happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply change .text() to .html().

.text() renders everything literally, while .html() renders normal HTML.

Comment: Changing the .text() to .html() does not work as the text required to be bold is outside the .text/.html. Even if I encapsulate the bold text in .html, the html bold < b>< /b> is still rendered to the screen.

Comment: It shouldn't be rendered literally in .html().  If it is, you have a syntax error.